# Django validate and go back to preview URL?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-validation

im asking again :), i don't know how make this.

My English is not too good, but ill try to asking this:

how ill validate a form and go back to the preview url (the same view form) and show the validation errors?, im asking this because i have 2 form's, the first form's action is going to a second form (POST), but in this second form (view?) i need to validate the first form, if the first form is valid i want to show the second form else ill show the first form with errors.

i dont know if im clear , im sorry.

im thinking about this:

```
def secondForm(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
       form = FirstForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          fields = request.POST.copy()
          # showing the second form?? with x differents fields, i have 2.
          if fields['xvalue']=='1': # this is from radio buttons
             form2 = xSecondForm()
          elif fields['xvalue']=='2':
             form2 = ySecondForm()
       else:
         # here go back with erros msgs????
         #return render_to_response('firstFormTemplate.html',{'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
      #return something or go back ???
```

Thanks guys
PD: im happy, im coding Django + python :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, formwizard might be your answer, but you could probably do it with some logic in a view.

Something like:

```
def your_view(request):
    context = {}
    data = request.method == 'POST' and request.POST or None
    form = FirstForm(data=data)
    # If the first form is valid, build the second.
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['xvalue'] == 1:
            form2 = xSecondForm(data=data)
        else:
            form2 = ySecondForm(data=data)
        context['form2'] = form2
    # If both forms are valid, everything is done.
    if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        # TODO: put save/processing logic here
        # Now redirect.
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect(...)
    # If we get here, either there hasn't been a post yet, the second form hasn't
    # been entered, or there was an error in either form.
    context['form'] = form
    return render_to_response(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys,  i think that mi solution is FormWizard :)

but im not clear with something about my Second Form, because i need to show the second form in different way if the selected option in radio is for more or less fields (in the second form)

;(

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use process_step() to do some logic on how/what do display in your second form.